# What is the meaning of 'Roonil Wazlib'?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, Ron accidentally writes his name as 'Roonil Wazlib'. Does this name have a reason or meaning behind it or is it just a random name?

Comment: It's a corruption of Ronald Weasley

Comment: This is a textbook case of "it's really not that deep".

Comment: I really don't think this question warrants any downvotes, let alone *six*.

Comment: It’s Wayne Rooney’s variant from a different timeline  

Answer (score 4):

Ron has a malfunctioning magic quill. It's supposed to take dictation and spell-check it for him, but it's broken. Note that it's not turning words into *other real words*, but rather turning them into vaguely fonetik nonsense.

Roonil Wazlib, in this instance is merely a corruption of Ronald Weasley.

> ‘How d’you spell “**belligerent**”?’ said Ron, shaking his quill very hard
> while staring at his parchment. ‘It can’t be **B – U – M –**’
>
> ‘No, it isn’t,’ said Hermione, pulling Ron’s essay towards her. ‘And
> “**augury**” doesn’t begin **O – R – G** either. What kind of quill are you
> using?’
>
> ‘It’s one of Fred and George’s Spell-Checking ones … but I think the
> charm must be wearing off …’
>
> ‘Yes, it must,’ said Hermione, pointing at the title of his essay,
> ‘because we were asked how we’d deal with **Dementors, not “Dugbogs”**,
> and I don’t remember you changing **your name to “Roonil Wazlib”**,
> either.’
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince</sup></sub>
>
> [image]